# how to copy only distinct values from one table to another in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySql database round-about 2.5GB,

The table[A] has following columns, `|anoid| |query| |date| |item-rank| |url|`

I have just created  another table[b] having columns only `|query|` and `|date|`

I want to insert all the distinct records in query column, with it's respective date, from Table[A] to [B], is there any fast query?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: so you want unique values in query column? what if there are multiple rows with same query and different (or same) dates? Or perhaps you want unique combination of the two columns?

Comment: sir. only unique values in query column.with its repected date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Tableb(query, date)
SELECT query, MAX(Date) AS MAXDate
FROM Tablea
GROUP BY query
```

This will give you distinct `query` with the most recent `date`.

Comment: @Shafiullah - please post the full error you got. The query I posted shouldn't give a syntax error it is correct.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unique(query,date)  select query, max(date) As maxdate from 500k group by query' at line 1

Comment: @Shafiullah - There is no `unique(query,date)` in my query. It is something you added by yourself. Can you please update your question with the full query you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
insert into table[b](query,date)
select query,date from table[a] order by table[a] asc
```

Comment: sir but TableA has many repeted values . i  just want only distinct of query column with its respected date .

Comment: select distinct query,date  from table[a]

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tableB
SELECT * FROM tableA
group by query
```

Note: please remove id from both the tables while applying the above query.